# FullCalendar v6.1 has `Table header cell is missing a header role` ADA issue on GridCalender view using SiteImprove free chrome extension

Tags: fullcalendar, accessibility, wai-aria, fullcalendar-6

## The Problem

I'm not sure what to do to fix the Calendar page issue, `Table header cell is missing a header role`. It seems to be having issues with the `<th role="presentation>` tag as shown in the following image.

[image]

## What I've Tried

So far I've tried adding `scope="col"`, `scope="row"`, `role="columnheader"`, as well as `role="rowheader"` and none of those seem to make that error go away. Is this an bug report to FullCalendar? Any ideas what else I should do to fix it in case I need to report it as a bug?

Comment: If you think there's an issue in fullcalendar please report it - see https://fullcalendar.io/reporting-bugs .

Answer (score 1):

How much control do you have over the HTML that is generated by the calendar?  There's **way too much** aria specified in that code. A lot of it is superfluous and some of it is just plain wrong.  I think there are several issues causing siteimprove to flag things in error.

First off, if you are using native semantic HTML for a table, most of the `role` attributes are not necessary.  For example, `<tr>` does not need `role="row"` because [you get that by default](https://w3c.github.io/html-aria/#el-tr).  Same with `<th>`, you'll get a default `role="columnheader"` if you use `scope="col"`.  Remove those roles.

Secondly, semantic table elements have built in roles, as mentioned above, so you **should not** override those roles with `role="presentation"`.  That removes the semantic value of that element.  For example, you have `<tr role="presentation"`>, `<th role="presentation"`> and `<thead role="presentation">`. Remove all the `role="presentation"`.

You also have `<table role="grid">` on the main table.  A [grid role](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#grid) is ok if you plan on implementing arrow key navigation to move between rows and columns (similar to how you navigate around a spreadsheet). I tried a simple [FullCalendar demo](https://fullcalendar.io/demos) and the arrow keys did **not** work, so `role="grid"` should **not** be used.  The dates in the calendar were <kbd>tab</kbd> focusable, which is fine, but that's just a regular table and not a grid.

Since there are so many problems with the generated table code, it's hard to say what is causing the siteimprove errors but start by cleaning up all the roles if you have control over that. If you don't have that level of control, I would **not** use that calendar because it is not accessible.